# How to prevent System.OutOfMemoryException when retrieving large amounts of data in c#

Tags: c#

I have a C# program that populates a dictionary with 4Million Guids at startup.
I keep getting an Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' error at this point.

Example:

```
using (reportingconn)
{
    var initialrowkeys = reportingconn.Query("select rowkey from table”);
}
```

Can anyone give me some ideas how best to retrieve large amounts data from SQL into a dictionary?

Comment: Do you really need all 4 million at once? are you looking for a specific one?

Comment: Why do you need to populate 4 million guids at startup?  That is the problem here.

Comment: I love this question - classic case of something grizzled old programmers would never ask and young programmers rarely have to consider (stream your data, small RAM).

Comment: @Brad I need to use those guids to retrieve data from Azure table storage n a loop. I do not want to keep hitting the database every-time.

Comment: @user1526912 If you really are using every single one that's fine, but it's worth ensuring that you can't filter the data on the DB end first.

Comment: Databases are meant to store large amounts of data and be able to handle large numbers of queries.  I'd be more worried about a query returning millions of results than hitting the database for data on-demand.

Comment: Are you processing these GUIDs sequentially, or do you actually need all of them at the same time (ignoring the multiple query performance consideration)?

Answer (score 5):

Use `SqlDataReader()` this will read row by row, instead of `SqlDataAdapter.Fill.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a 2GB memory limitation on C# data dictionary. A programmer friend told me to change my console application from 32 bit to 64 bit to prevent that limitaion. That seems to have resolved my problem.

Comment: I would guess the limit is more like 2 GB of contiguous addressable memory. [Some Good reading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx)